# unexplained error in sql execution

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

```
UPDATE amc_machine b
    SET     with_parts = a.with_parts,
        amc_validity_upto = a.amc_validity_upto
        FROM (SELECT CASE
            WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (machine_id) with_parts, amc_validity_upto, machine_id
                        FROM amc_amcdetail
                        WHERE machine_id = 2 AND id != 1
                        ORDER BY machine_id, amc_validity_upto DESC)
            WHEN count(*) = 0 THEN (SELECT FALSE AS with_parts, NULL AS amc_validity_upto, 2 AS machine_id)
            END AS a
            FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (machine_id) with_parts, amc_validity_upto, machine_id
                        FROM amc_amcdetail
                        WHERE machine_id = 2
                        ORDER BY machine_id, amc_validity_upto
                        ) AS T) AS foo
        WHERE a.machine_id = b.id
```

The error shown is

```
ERROR:  subquery must return only one column
LINE 5:    WHEN count(*) > 0 THEN (SELECT DISTINCT ON (machine_id) w...
```

Can anyone tell what seems to be the problem.
Basically the query is to update on table b with data from table a if exists, else update with null , false as the case is.

The query executes when standalone. I am using Postgres 9.3, but deployment will be on postgres9.1

Comment: does your table have multiple rows for the same machine_id.? here are there more than one rwo for machine_id = 2?

Comment: yes, thats why the query is using distinct on to return only one row

Answer (score 0):

The subquery returns 3 columns

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (machine_id) with_parts, amc_validity_upto, machine_id
```

Make it return only one

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (machine_id) with_parts
```

Comment: ok had not seen columns, assumed rows!!!
but i need three columns for the update. Can the subquery not return more than on columns. I have use subqueries before which returned many columns